# RealURL gives me http://www.domain.com/4/ links

Tags: typo3, realurl

I set up a fresh TYPO3 4.7.5 and installed RealURL 1.12.3. If I active RealURL my URLs don't work because I get links like

`http://www.domain.com/4/`
`http://www.domain.com/7/`

What I'm doing wrong? Seems that I forgot something.

I put this in my main template

```
config {
        baseURL = http://www.domain.com/
        simulateStaticDocuments = 0
        tx_realurl_enable = 1 
}
```

Furthermore I enabled automtic configuration.

Despite this I added a manual configuration (`typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`):

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * aeUrlTool default realurl configuration
 * based on realurl-configuration of news.typo3.org
 *  http://news.typo3.org/about/realurl-configuration/
 *
 */

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array ( 
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
        ),
        'redirects' => array (
            'sitemap.xml' => 'sitemap-xml',
        ),
        'preVars' => array (
            '0' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'nc' => '1',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            '1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => '0',
                    'en' => '1',
                    'it' => '2',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            '2' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'lang',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => 'de',
                    'en' => 'en',
                    'it' => 'it',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => '7',
            'rootpage_id' => '1',
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array (
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array (
            '_DEFAULT' => array (
                'archive' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[year]',
                    ),
                    '1' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[month]',
                        'valueMap' => array (
                            'january' => '01',
                            'february' => '02',
                            'march' => '03',
                            'april' => '04',
                            'may' => '05',
                            'june' => '06',
                            'july' => '07',
                            'august' => '08',
                            'september' => '09',
                            'october' => '10',
                            'november' => '11',
                            'december' => '12',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'browse' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pointer]',
                    ),
                ),
                'select_category' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[cat]',
                    ),
                ),
                'article' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array (
                            'table' => 'tt_news',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    '1' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[swords]',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'fileName' => array (
//
// if you don't want .html-URLs set the following to "false" (e.g. 'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => false,)
// then you get http://www.yourdomain.com/imprint/ instead of http://www.yourdomain.com/imprint.html
//
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => true,
            'index' => array (
                'rss.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '100',
                    ),
                ),
                'rss091.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '101',
                    ),
                ),
                'rdf.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '102',
                    ),
                ),
                'atom.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '103',
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ),
    ),

); 

?>
```

My `.htaccess` looks like

```
#####
# 
# Example .htaccess file
# 
# This file contains a collection of almost everything you will need
# for optimising TYPO3:
# 
# - mod_rewrite (used for SimulateStaticDocuments, RealUrl, etc.)
# - PHP optimisation
# 
# If you want to use it, you'll need to rename this file to '.htaccess'.
# (To make this work you will need to adjust the 'AllowOverride'
# directive in your Apache configuration file.)
# 
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3
# installation!
# 
# You should change every occurance of TYPO3root/ to the location where you
# have your website in. For example:
# If you have your website located at http://mysite.com/
# then your TYPO3root/ is just empty (remove 'TYPO3root/')
# If you have your website located at http://mysite.com/some/path/
# then your TYPO3root/ is some/path/ (search and replace)
# 
# If you have problems with this file, try using the minimal
# mod_rewrite.htaccess which is located in the typo3_src/misc/
# directory of this installation.
# 
# You can also use this configuration in your httpd.conf, but you'll have
# to modify some lines, see the comments (search for 'httpd.conf')
# 
# Using rewriting in your httpd.conf is much faster, btw.
# 
# Questions about this file go to the matching Install mailing list,
# see http://typo3.org/documentation/mailing-lists/
# 
####


### Begin: Rewrite stuff ###

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# To assist in debugging rewriting, you could use these lines
# DON'T enable it for production!
# This will only work in httpd.conf, not in .htaccess files
#RewriteLog /var/log/apache/rewrite.log
#RewriteLogLevel 9

# If you use the RealUrl extension, then you'll have to enable the next line.
# You will have to change this path if your TYPO3 installation is located
# in a subdirectory of the website root.
# 
# If you place this in httpd.conf, you cannot use this directive in any case!
#RewriteBase /

# Stop rewrite processing if we are in the typo3/ directory
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/(typo3/|t3lib/|tslib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|tslib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Redirect http://mysite/typo3 to http://mysite/typo3/index_re.php
# and stop the rewrite processing
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/typo3$ /TYPO3root/typo3/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php
# Important note: If you copy/paste this into httpd.conf instead
# of .htaccess you will need to add '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}' left to each
# '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' part.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Main URL rewriting.

# If you use Windows and SimulateStaticDocuments do not work, try adding a
# slash (/) right before 'index.php' below.

# The example shows how to rewrite only *.html and *.pdf files to index.php
# This may be helpful when using an extension that can generate PDF files
# on the fly.
# Example: RewriteRule .*\.(html|pdf)$ index.php [L]

# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one that has no '#':
# RewriteRule .* /TYPO3root/index.php [L]

# For use with the RealUrl extension, you might need to remove the
# RewriteBase directive somewhere above and use this line instead of the
# next one:
# RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

### End: Rewrite stuff ###

### Begin: PHP optimisation ###

# All features below are left to the default if you don't change this.
# Simply remove the comment marks if you want to use some/all of these
# settings

# The PHP developers recommend disabling this feature. Do that.
# It's deprecated and is likely to be unsupported in future versions of PHP.
#php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference off

# TYPO3 works fine with register_globals turned off.
# This is highly recommended!
#php_flag register_globals off

# PHP may not declare the argv & argc variables (that would contain the GET
# information).
# TYPO3 doesn't need this, so just turn it off.
#php_flag register_argc_argv off

# Magic quotes for runtime-generated data (data from SQL, exec(), etc.)
#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

# Order in which PHP registers GET, POST, Cookie and Built-in variables
#php_value variables_order GPCS

### End: PHP optimisation ###

### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled
#Options -Indexes

# There is a problem with Internet Explorer and mod_gzip on Apache servers.
# For more information, see
# http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/rtehtmlarea/Tutorial-79/
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.css$
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.png$
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.gif$
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.jpg$
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.jpeg$
#mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.js$

### End: Miscellaneous ###

# Add your own rules here
# ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create domain record in root of the tree.

Then:

1. together with automatic configuration it should works out of the
   box.
2. or if you want to make it manually then you need to add in realurl conf following lines at the end of that file (typo3conf/realurl.conf):

> ```
> $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['example.com'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
> unset($TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']);
> ```

If you use manual realurl config then double check if realurl extension manager read proper file for manual config. Look here:
[image]

Comment: I added the domain records for my domain to the element with id=1.There are multiple entries with www and without. But that didn't changed anything. Where should I put the lines? In the `realurl_conf.php`? Or `localconf.php`?

Comment: In realurl_conf.php but check for my updated answer if you read the right file.

Comment: I deactivated automatic configuration and it worked. Now I actived it again and it still worked. Seems that the update of these settings did it for me.

Comment: Realurl automatic configuration creates such lines`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['example.com'] = ...` itself so I think that adding the domain record in root page did the trick for automatic configuration. That how it should be at least.

Comment: Thanks Krystian! After updating RealUrl to version 1.12.3 it was broken. These 2 steps fixed the problem: 1) turn OFF the option Enable automatic configuration and 2) create typo3conf/realurl.php with all configuration variables of type $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']. I found my old config in AdditionalConfiguration.php created by TYPO3 6.0.0 Updater.

Answer (score 1):

im my case I needed to go into database/phpmyadmin and delete all cached real url entries there. After deleting all entries in realurl tables it worked fine.